# Threads deletion

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I encountered on problem with deleting or shutdown certain threads within my command line java application. When main method is in the end, still are running some threads redundant.

On the following lines are my all running threads in the end of main method:

```
pool-1-thread-5; Is Daemon false;Is Alive true
pool-1-thread-2; Is Daemon false;Is Alive true
AMQP Connection xx.xx.x.xxx:5672; Is Daemon false;Is Alive true
Finalizer; Is Daemon true;Is Alive true
Reference Handler; Is Daemon true;Is Alive true
main; Is Daemon false;Is Alive true
Signal Dispatcher; Is Daemon true;Is Alive true
pool-1-thread-3; Is Daemon false;Is Alive true
pool-1-thread-4; Is Daemon false;Is Alive true
```

I don't know origin of all pool* threads and AMQP thread, rest is ok, because they are daemon threads and main thread

My goal is get rid pool* threads and AMQP thread without using of System.exit() and CTRL+C in terminal

I have tried following method in the end of main:

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().forEach((t) -> {
            if(t.getName().startsWith("pool") || t.getName().startsWith("AMQP"))  {
                t.stop();
                t.destroy();
            }
        });
```

But always I receive exception, I have tried to use only stop method, only destroy.
Have you please some idea, how can I trace source of redundant threads or simplify how can I them destroy

Thank you

Comment: Well, you must be using AMQP somewhere (e.g. RabbitMQ), and forgot to close the connection. The pool threads are likely used by the message queue framework. Suggest you **read the documentation** of whatever MQ library you're using to see how to correctly shut it down.

Comment: Thank you Andreas